# php instant search crashing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, search

I have created an instant search for MYSQL database using php and jquery. the search is functioning properly until I delete some of the keyword search terms and begin the search again. Once search terms are deleted by the user the search results are no longer being returned as expected. Once this occurs if I refresh the page I receive a "no data received" message from the browser and the site does not go online again for a minute or so. In order to see what i mean you can go to www.partsearch.club .. some of the keywords that can be used are "decora connector wet bx tek tk". If you continue to add and remove search terms you will see what I mean. Here is my code

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Instant Search Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<center><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search..." size="50"><br />
</br>
<form><input type=button value="Refresh" onClick="history.go()"></form>    </center><br />
<div id="searchresults"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

search.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Instant Search Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$hostname = "localhost"; 


mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
mysql_select_db("wesco");

$searchArray = explode(" ", $_POST['searchterm']);
$query = "";
foreach($searchArray as $val) {
$search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($val));
if (!empty($query)) {
    $query = $query . " AND "; // or AND, depends on what you want
}

$query = $query . "`keywords` LIKE '%$search%'";
}

if (!empty($query)) {
$find_parts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `parts` WHERE $query");
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_parts))
{
$name = $row['name'];

echo "<center>$name</center><br />";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

search.js

```
$('#search').keyup(function()
{
var searchterm = $('#search').val();

if(searchterm!='')
{
    $.post('search.php',{searchterm:searchterm},
    function(data)
    {
        $('#searchresults').html(data);
    });
}
else
{
    $('#searchresults').html('');   
}
});
```

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);` to the top of your script, are any errors reported?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any firewall, or using varnish or a reverse proxy in front of apache? Are you setting any rate limit on the amount of requests, anywhere on your apache settings? I tried to overload the server by doing several autocomplete requests and eventually got blocked, however at the same exact moment I tried from another box on another ip and I got a correct answer:

```
curl -X GET -I http://www.partsearch.club/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 06 Feb 2016 01:42:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

So this shows that the server is not going down for everyone, but rather that I was blocked for a few seconds, probably by Apache or any Ddos protection you may have in your server. I would suggest trying nginx or litespeed as a webserver, to check if the problem lies on Apache or somewhere else.